# When creating a scrollview

Tags: android, layout, view

I am creating a scrollview dynamically and I had a very basic question.  Is the `ScrollView()` by default have vertical scrolling?  Do I have to set it using this: `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);` ?  If not what would I use to create the vertical scroll?

My code I am using this in:

```
ScrollView sV = new ScrollView(getActivity());
sV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
sV.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Comment: yes ScrollView is a verticle scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ScrollView` adds vertical scrolling. In order to add horizontal scrolling, use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). So, you don't have to `sV.setVerticalScrollBarEnable(true)`, scrollbar will be added when content is larger than device screen.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use a custom ListView instead?

Comment: Basically the grand scheme of what I am trying to accomplish inside this scroll view is I am retrieving items of a game from a database, so I don't know the size of whats being returned, which consist of an image + money (amount the item cost) + description of the item.  So I am trying to create a dynamic layout inside of this scrollview which will consist of other layouts.

Comment: But actually let me do some research on some custom listviews cause that may make my life easier.  Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView` is always scrolling vertical (if enough widgets/elements inside).
For horizontal scrolling the `HorizontalScrollView` is used.

As Neo mentioned, if you  want to add Content dynamically a ListView might be the better choice.